# how to fix Wordpress website background image ?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a website that needs to be fixed like other website.

Please see my website. I want fixed background but that shows in scrolling not fixed:

http://mikekingusa.com/

I want to do like this website background: http://wikiwarnings.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add that to your body css

`background-attachment: fixed;`